# I want to delete records from my table which is not present in temporary table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

**ImageTable**

```
Id Image_Id Image_Name
----------------------
5252      100      test.png
5252      101      info.png
5252      102      info.png
5253      103      gana.png
5253      104      tera.png
5254      105      saga.png
```

I pass Temporary Table like this

**Temp_Image**

```
Id  Image_Id  Image_Name
----------------------
5252      100      test.png
```

I want to combine this two tables and update ImageTable with Id = 5252 and Image_Id=100 and delete all records which having Id  5252

The result should be

**ImageTable**

```
Id Image_Id Image_Name
----------------------
5252      100      test.png
5253      103      gana.png
5253      104      tera.png
5254      105      saga.png
```

How to achieve this? I have tried many ways but couldn't get result in my way.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
DELETE A
FROM ImageTable as A
INNER JOIN Temp_Image as B   --make sure all the Id present in the Temp_Image table
ON B.Id = A.ID 
LEFT JOIN Temp_Image as C   -- delete all the records that do not have matching Image_Id
ON B.Id = A.Id 
AND B.Image_Id = A.Image_Id
WHERE C.Image_Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

First you delete and then insert.  I think you want code like this

```
delete it
from
  ImageTable it
 join
  Temp_Image ti on it.Id=ti.Id;

insert ImageTable
select * from Temp_Image;
```